# slurm - I/O shared between to nodes? Is that possible?

Tags: slurm

I am working with NGS data and the newest test files are massive.

Normally our pipeline is using just one node and the output from different tools is its ./scratch folder.

To use just one node is not possible with the current massive data set. That's why I would like to use at least 2 nodes to solve the issues such as speed, not all jobs are submitted, etc.

Using multiple nodes or even multiple partitions is easy - i know how which parameter to use for that step.

So my issue is not about missing parameters, but the logic behind slurm to solve the following issue about I/O:

Lets say I have tool-A. Tool-A is running with 700 jobs on two nodes (340 jobs on node1 and 360 jobs on node2) - the ouput is saved on ./scratch on each node separately.

Tool-B is using the results from tool-A - which are on two different nodes.

What is the best approach to fix that?
- Is there a parameter which tells slurm which jobs belongs together and where to find the input for tool-B?
- would it be smarter to change the output on /scratch to a local-folder?
- or would it be better to merge the output from tool-A from both nodes to one node?
- any other ideas?

I hope I made my issue "simply" to understand... Please apologize if that is not the case!

Comment: SLURM currently does not support data aware job allocation. All the solutions that you suggest could work for you if implemented correctly. As it stands your question is a bit too broad for this forum. By the way, there are commercial products that extend SLURM functionality to provide data-aware scheduling.

Answer (score 0):

My naive suggestion would be why not share a scratch nfs volume across all nodes ? This way all ouput datas of ToolA would be acessible for ToolB  whatever the node. It migth not be the best solution for read/write speed, but to my mind it would be the easiest for your situation.
A more sofware solution (not to hard to develop) can be to implement a database that track where the files have been generated. 
I hope it help !

Answer (score 0):

... just for those coming across this via search engines: if you cannot use any kind of shared filesystem (NFS, GPFS, Lustre, Ceph) and you don't have only *massive* data sets, you could use "**staging**", meaning data transfer *before* and *after* your job really runs. 
Though this is termed "cast"ing in the Slurm universe, it generally means you define

- files to be copied to all nodes assigned to your job BEFORE the job starts
- files to be copied from nodes assigned to your job AFTER the job completes.

This can be a way to get everything needed back and forth from/to your job's nodes even without a shared file system.

Check the man page of "`sbcast`" and amend your sbatch job scripts accordingly.